# Trying to duplicate then rotate an Array in ruby - getting error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I've got an error. Essentially I'm copying a 2d array to another array. (so arrayCopy = $array)

and I'm trying to then rotate the array 90 degrees if that makes sense? 
Here is a diagram to help illustrate. https://gyazo.com/2183552cfe539406b3197e6329f9ba28 .

The code I am trying is this https://gyazo.com/61669116735ca96ce52115442a44e36c .

where essentially I am running through the size of the array and putting "rotating" the array.

However I'm getting the error here https://gyazo.com/d44d558987f7b7ae0b06678d76687213 .

Just wondering if I could get help debugging the error. 
I know the array is copying fine as I can output it. 
so I think its how I'm going about assigning the values? thanks for any help I can get.
I've tried a few different ways and cant seem to get this to work?

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: ...and then edit your question to replace the images with text.

Comment: You want `(0...MAZE_SIZE).map { |i| (0...MAZE_SIZE).map { |j| $maze[j][i] }  } #=> [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]] `, but a more Ruby-like way to do that is `$maze.transpose.map(&:reverse)`. To rotate in the opposite direction:  `$maze.map(&:reverse).transpose`.

Answer (score -1):

you should try

```
mazeCopy = Array.new(MAZE_SIZE){Array.new(MAZE_SIZE)}
for i in (0...MAZE_SIZE)
  for j in (0...MAZE_SIZE)
     mazeCopy[i][j] = $maze[j][i]
  end
end
# using triple dots to exclude the last value in the range
# error is occurring because you're trying to access value 
# outside the range of your array which gives nil.
```

See this example why this error is occurring:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
b = a
for i in (0..a.size)
  for j in (0..a.size)
    # when value of i or j reaches 3
    # b[3] => nil
    # b[3][] => [] on nil class error
    b[i][j] = a[j][i]
  end
end
```

Comment: Your code produces `mazeCopy #=> [[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3]]`, which is obviously incorrect. (Why didn't you test?) Moreover, since you merely assign `mazeCopy` to the object $maze, the latter is altered to equal the value of `mazeCopy` after the calculations are complete. You want to initially make `mazeCopy` (though now the name is misleading) an array of arrays with arbitrary values, unrelated to `$maze`; e.g., `mazeCopy = Array.new(MAZE_SIZE) { Array.new(MAZE_SIZE) } => [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]`. I therefore downvoted your answer.